# Run a Java Application (Maven) in a different machine from the one where it was developed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, jboss

My question is a bit "vague"...
I've deployed a Java application in Eclipse Kepler (on Windows 7), more specifically, a Maven project. It has many dependencies, namely, JBoss 5.1.0.GA (the server where I'm running the application).

Now, I want to be able install/run my application in any other machine, and start it without have to start Eclipse: through the command-line for example.

How should I start? How can I "carry" all the dependencies with the project, and do not depend from JBoss?

Comment: Have you checked with maven plugin http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/ , if I understand correctly you have java web application and you want to deploy it app to server which is in another machine in that case check with jboss plugin

Comment: Well I tried to provide the answer, but I think the answer can be a bit broad. So voting to close. Meanwhile try http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/ and JBoss Maven plugin. And ask a more targeted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to install the JBOSS application server in the machine where
  you want to deploy your project.
- You have to declare all your dependencies of your project in your
  pom.xml to avoid managing the dependencies manually. so, that Maven will create an archive file ,which will include all the required dependencies for your project to run independently. that's the main usage and goal of Maven build tool
- You need to create the archive file (.war or .ear) by using Maven
  tool. i.e `mvn install` command.

Comment: I'd better use mvn package instead of mvn install because it might have other side effects (depends on your poms).

Comment: i believe that mvn install is the later build phase than package. so, package build phase will happen and then only install will happen. May i know about the side effects

Comment: In general you are right. Side effects depends on the actual poms, i.e. what plugins it uses etc. Also it installs your artifacts (if they have) to the local repository. The question was solely about creating the war and package is definitely for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. And what about those .jar files that I had to add to my JBoss Deploy folder, to avoid the 'NoClassDefFoundError' when I ran my application? How can I export them with my .ear archive file and install them in another machine?

Comment: What are the .ear files that you have add in Deploy folder? Are they related to JBOSS / any third party libraries?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan They are .jar files related to my Talend Jobs, and also related to Jersey, that I run in my application